# How to write an infinite loop that an exception can't break?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, exception, infinite-loop

Is it possible to write an infinite loop that exceptions can't break out of even when the exceptions happen between executions of the loop body?  If so, how?  (These are the sort of silly things I think about when I ponder robustness.)

For example, consider the following code:

```
import time

def slow_true():
    print 'waiting to return True...'
    time.sleep(1.0)
    return True

while slow_true():
    try:
        print 'in loop body'
        raise RuntimeError('testing')
    except:
        print 'caught exception, continuing...'
        continue
```

I can easily break out of the loop with Ctrl-C while Python is executing `slow_true()`.  Even if I replace `while slow_true():` with `while True:` there is theoretically a small window of time (between executions of the body) where a `SIGINT` can cause the script to exit.

I realize I can implement a `SIGINT` handler to effectively disable Ctrl-C, but that's not the point of this question.

I could wrap the loop with another infinite loop and move the `try`/`except` out a level like so:

```
import time

def slow_true():
    print 'waiting to return True...'
    time.sleep(1.0)
    return True

while True:
    try:
        while slow_true():
            print 'in loop body'
            raise RuntimeError('testing')
    except:
        print 'caught exception, restarting...'
        continue
    break
```

This would make it much harder to break out of the loop (two exceptions would have to be raised back-to-back at just the right times), but I think it's still theoretically possible.

Comment: What's your problem here? It seems you are only trying to state facts or receive opinions rather than answers.

Comment: @PythonMaster:  I don't have a problem—I have a question.  That question is stated at the beginning:  "Is it possible to write an infinite loop that exceptions can't break out of even when the exceptions happen between executions of the loop body?"

Comment: Well you should avoid yes/no questions really.

Comment: @PythonMaster:  There's an implied "If so, how?" question there.  I'll edit my question to make that implied question explicit.

Comment: @PythonMaster Yes/no questions still require proof. Ifs its possible, then a code example or proof from the documentation would be required. If no, then some sources to the contrary would be needed.

Comment: Why not just `signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)`?

Comment: @augurar:  That works for `KeyboardInterrupt`, but not other exceptions (e.g., some exception raised in a `SIGUSR1` handler).

Answer (score 4):

One definitely not recommended option is to override the excepthook method.

```
import sys

def exception_hook(exception_type, value, traceback):
    your_loop_function()

sys.excepthook = exception_hook
```

Alternative solution using signals (less bad):

```
import signal

def interrupt(signal, frame):
    your_loop_function()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, interrupt)
```

Comment: So this will block exceptions from being thrown? Or will the exceptions just trigger this function (`exception_hook`)?

Comment: The exceptions will trigger the function so you can keep going. Alternatively you'll be stacking try/except blocks forever as you pointed out.

Comment: Clever.  What happens if `your_loop_function()` itself raises an exception?

Comment: @RichardHansen: an infinite loop which will trigger a maximum recursion depth error, which... well this could definitely kill your interpreter. Which is why I definitely don't recommend it ;)

Comment: How does that alternative solution prevent exceptions from breaking the loop?  Are exceptions disabled while handling signals?  What if there was a `SIGUSR1` handler that raised an exception?

Comment: The normal try/except would still be required with the alternative solution, it only handles the `SIGINT` (ctrl+c) signal. Exceptions work as normal within signals so any exceptions within that would still kill it. But at least the ctrl+c (which is the culprit of actually killing through try/except blocks) will be caught. As for a `SIGUSR1`, that's still an option of course. But you couldn't do that from within the script anyhow :)

Comment: The first solution doesn't work, a second `SIGINT` after the first will not be successfully caught.

Comment: @RichardHansen Actually it seems the exception hook only catches the first exception, if another exception is thrown within the exception hook it is not intercepted.  Hence my previous comment.

Comment: Second one doesn't work either, probably because due to a bug or bugs in the interpreter.  If you send a constant stream of `SIGINT`s to the python process, it will terminate.

Comment: @augurar:  You're right about the first not working.  I haven't tried the second, but I imagine if you throw enough `SIGINT`s at the process the stack will grow too deep and the interpreter will bail, but the loop would always be running until that point.  Does that seem right?

Comment: @augurar:  The second one doesn't defend against an exception raised in a `SIGUSR1` handler, I think (I haven't tried it).  So, even if lots of `SIGINT`s can't break the loop, I don't think the second solution is fully robust either.

Comment: @RichardHansen  I think handling a signal resets the call stack, so stack depth is not a problem.  When I tested it, the process exited with an interrupted status (no traceback), which I believe means that the interpreter  itself failed to handle one of the `SIGINT`s.

Comment: It seems the interpreter is protecting us from stupid behaviour, the only thing that might still work is overriding `sys.__excepthook__` instead.